# Major software release in little over 12 hours - where is everyone?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

Cyberdyne have been working on a new operating system for some time (years?).  It's due to be released in around 13 hours when Sarah, Kyle and Pops arrive at the Cyberdyne offices.

They head in through the main entrance, where there are seemingly just 4 or 5 security guards *all in the same place*.  Given the size of the facility, why aren't there more spread around (at least in the entrances to the other buildings) that must surely have heard and responded to gunfire.

Also, given the scale of the worldwide reception to the new operating system, with giant billboards everywhere and everyone seemingly talking about it, why are the offices deserted with such a huge launch *literally in a few hours*.  Inside the building I would expect technicians monitoring everything, managers making sure the technicians are ok etc.  Hell, even the overnight cleaning staff ought to be around making sure it all looks good for the media.

Speaking of the media, where are all the Outside Broadcast trucks that would surely be being set up to cover such an event?

In short - where *is* everyone?

Comment: It could be that while it was developed there, it's not the head office.

Comment: Possibly, but Danny Dyson already held one press conference outside these offices, and even if that's the case, it only really explains the lack of media outside - the offices themselves ought to still be busy.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how they work, but it could be that they separate development and infrastructure enough that development are aware of releases but aren't in the least involved. That's how it generally is with large companies like that. IIRC it was night-time. Maybe everyone just went home for the night as usual.

Comment: Working in software, in my eyes it would be very strange to have absolutely _no one_ monitoring the mainframe, which is onsite, 12 hours before a worldwide, highly anticipated software release.  It could just be something as mundane as a faulty hard drive that needs to be pulled and replaced, but you need someone physically there to do it.

Comment: I forgot the mainframe. I can't remember the film now, I saw it in the cinema way too long ago. Maybe you're right and it's just bad writing.

Comment: I also work in software.  A major release like this would absolutely require an "all hands on deck" approach.  The building would have been highly populated, even those people that had nothing to do would have had their manager "ask" them to be there.

Comment: _"managers making sure the technicians are ok"_ Heh, have you ever worked in a company?

Comment: Since there's obviously no in-universe explanation, I'm not sure what sort of answer you're fishing for here? No, Cyberdyne is not a realistic interpretation of such a company. _That's_ your problem with a movie about time-travelling killer robots?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Revisiting this today, I'm not really sure now.  I guess I was wondering if there may have been any other published information (I think there's at least one or two books out there that people may have read) / interviews etc where this point may have come up

Comment: lol ok...​​​​​​

Comment: Maybe **Genysis** was already released; *[softly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_launch#Hardware)*, Genysis was just "upgrading" in preparation for a "hard launch" or "public launch". Additionally, we could assume that the engineers had done a ton of testing and preparation to [automate the deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Automate_deployment) process (which is something that's done quite regularly in the real IT industry).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's wrong to think about it as a regular release of some major software project. In such big projects, a lot of people are involved in creating the software, which is the reason why a lot of them need to be in the office before a big launch to make sure it goes smoothly.

In this timeline however Genisys was mostly created by John Connor/T-3000 and Danny Dyson. At least its most critical parts. Here's the conversation between them and  Miles Dyson.

> — It's a shame you won't take a more public role in the company, John. Danny is the best there is, and even he can't decipher some of the enhanced code you've integrated into Genisys.
>
> — I just know it works.
>
> — Cyberdyne owes you, John. I owe you.
>
> — Miles, your faith in me is payment enough.

As for the media, even though it's a big launch, I don't think they would snow up at night 13 hours prior, when there's nothing supposed to be going on.